# Can a local Tcl socket -server deliver audio on HTTP and concurrently respond to requests over a web socket?

Tags: tcl, html5-audio

I'm using Tcl as a local server to run an application in a web browser and, so far, while building it, I've been able to open it in multiple tabs in the same browser and in multiple browsers opened concurrently on the same desktop without any issue. Web sockets are used for most of the requests. All of the requests, thus far, have been short-lived SQLite queries.

I'd like to be able to play audio (lectures) in the application while giving the user the ability to make requests against the database, in order that they may view some of the information while listening.

I must be doing something stupid or expecting too much. First, the application is opened in one browser tab, a web socket opened and requests return data from the SQLite database. Then a second tab is opened (it ultimately won't need to be two tabs but am doing this just to test) and the audio is requested and starts playing. The audio is a separate file and not in the database; and the audio is requested via HTTP and not on the web socket used for the data requests. After the audio is requested, the Tcl server does not respond to other requests, even on the web sockets. If the browser tab playing the audio is closed, then requests are processed again, without having to reload the tab or restartng the server.

The procedure to send the audio file is pretty simple.

```
proc ::HTTP::REQ::SendFile {sock filename type} {
  set fp [open $filename rb];  # NB: rb — b is for BINARY; this is important.
  set size [file size $filename]
  # HTTP spec says headers are ISO 8859-1 and CRLF-separated
  # chan configure $sock -encoding iso8859-1 -blocking 0 -translation crlf -buffering full
  chan puts $sock "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  chan puts $sock "Content-Type: $type; charset=utf-8"
  chan puts $sock "Content-Length: $size"
  chan puts $sock "Connection: Keep-Alive"
  chan puts $sock ""
  chan flush $sock

  # Ship the data in binary mode; fcopy is VERY efficient.
  chan configure $sock -translation binary
  chan copy $fp $sock -size $size
  close $fp
```

When I close the tab playing audio, the error generated is:

```
error writing "sock5605cc3a4720": connection reset by peer
    while executing
"chan copy $fp $sock -size $size"
```

Thus, I suppose the audio file is not written to the browser in one segment. Also, if advance the audio by clicking on the progress bar until it gets about 2/3rds complete, then the web socket starts functioning again and when close the audio tab, the above error is not generated.

Would you please tell me if the Tcl server is supposed to be able to handle playing audio over HTTP and responding to web socket requests concurrently? And, if so, what am I doing wrong to cause this sort of a blocking situation?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I think I found an answer, at least something that works. It's the `-command` option of the [fcopy](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/fcopy.html) or `chan copy` command. Changed the above code to that below and can, now, listen to the audio and request data on the web socket concurrently and immediately.

If there is a better way or something more to know about this approach, please point me to it.

Also, if you can, would you please explain what takes place between Tcl and the browser such that the fcopy takes place slowly. I mean does Tcl send the file in pieces as requested by the browser without having to write code to send it in chunks, or something like that?
And is it "okay" if it takes 26 minutes of audio to play before the copy completes? I tested on a 40MB mp3 that is ~ 45 minutes in length and it took about 26 minutes before the callback was executed.

Thank you.

```
proc ::HTTP::REQ::SendFile {sock filename type} {
  set fp [open $filename rb];   # NB: rb — b is for BINARY; this is important.
  set size [file size $filename]
  # HTTP spec says headers are ISO 8859-1 and CRLF-separated
  # chan configure $sock -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf -buffering full
  chan puts $sock "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  chan puts $sock "Content-Type: $type; charset=utf-8"
  chan puts $sock "Content-Length: $size"
  chan puts $sock "Connection: Keep-Alive"
  chan puts $sock ""
  chan flush $sock

  # Ship the data in binary mode; fcopy is VERY efficient
  chan configure $sock -translation binary
  chan copy $fp $sock -size $size -command [list ::HTTP::REQ::ChanCopyCleanup $fp $sock]
  chan puts "chan copy a.k.a. fcopy is not blocking"
  # close $fp
}

proc ::HTTP::REQ::ChanCopyCleanup {fp sock bytes {error {}} } {
  close $fp
  ::HTTP::ResetSock $sock
  chan puts stdout "Closed the file"
}
```

EDIT: After some further experimenting and reading, found that the browser simply ignores the `preload` request and stops loading at some point a few minutes into the audio. I should write that it buffers only so much and stops. How that communciation between Tcl and the browser works to transfer more data as needed, I suppose, is all part of the events between channels; and no other Tcl code is required. Without the `-command` option, this behavior of the browser resulted in Tcl blocking at `fcopy`. (The audio is sent through HTTP and not the above mentioned websocket; the socket is for the SQLite requests only.)

However, that is not my objective because I'd like to make something like a link that can open an audio source to a requested time position. To do that requires something like the ignored preload; so, used an object url. The following example works fine and takes about 300ms to transfer the 40 MB audio file and start it at 30 minutes. This is all local on the desktop, which is the only place it will be used; for this is not a network applcation but only using the browser for a UI. Thus, working in this manner, the `-command` to not block on `fcopy` is of almost no importance; but will continue to use it, of course.

```
  let d = Date.now();
  let iObj = { method: 'GET' };
  fetch( "http://127.0.0.11:8000/audio.mp3", iObj )
  .then( response => {
      console.log("Got a response.");
      if ( !response.ok ) {
        console.log( 'Network response was not ok.' );
      } else {
        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('audio/mpeg')) {
          throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got an audio file!");
        }
      }
      return response.blob();
    })
  .then( result => {
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( result );
    let a = document.createElement("AUDIO");
    // a.preload="auto";
    a.src = objectURL;
    a.controls = true;
    a.style.width="100%";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    /*
      Perhaps, it just needs time to load the source and then
      object url can be revoked and memory released.
    */
    a.oncanplaythrough = () => {
       URL.revokeObjectURL( objectURL );
       a.currentTime = 1800;
       console.log( Date.now() - d);
       /*
         WARNING This event fires every time the user clicks
         on the timeline UI element. Thus, once revoke the
         object url, reset this to nothing.
       */
       a.oncanplaythrough = null;
    };
   })
  .catch( e => {
    console.log( "Error in fetch." );
    console.log( e )
   })
   ;
```

Comment: Without `-command`, `chan copy` is defined to be blocking. Or at least is allowed to be (these things get complicated with stacked channel transforms).

Answer (score 0):

### Issue #1

> I think I found an answer, at least something that works. It's the `-command` option of the `fcopy` or `chan copy` command.

The `-command` option is required for this mode of operation. The [documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fcopy.htm) says:

> Without the **-command** option, **fcopy** blocks until the copy is complete [...]
>
> The **-command** argument makes **fcopy** work in the background.

### Issue #2

> Also, if you can, would you please explain what takes place between Tcl and the browser such that the fcopy takes place slowly.

`fcopy` *itself* is fast, especially when doing a binary-to-binary copy, as it looks at what the operating system considers to be the optimal block size for transfers and tries to avoid buffer copies.

However, when you're then wrapping that in additional machinery to turn it into a web socket then there may be additional overhead. Websockets are quite complex internally! If the sub-protocol you're implementing uses binary frames, then the problem you're probably seeing is due to the frame header overhead; shrinking the maximum block size slightly will help since then each block will work as a sensible number of network packets. If the sub-protocol is a text protocol, then you've got a *lot* more overhead for binary data; it'd quite possibly be being converted to base-64 text (substantial overhead!) and then wrapped in JSON (some fairly small overhead per frame) and then having the overall frame header on top of that (OTOH, using STOMP like that does give you message routing; you get something for all that overhead).

In case you hadn't guessed, I think bulk binary data is better moved by binary frames or even their own outright HTTP(S) transfers, which work very well for that.

Exactly what's going wrong is not 100% clear, but when you start to put in a bunch of layers then the computation and overhead can definitely add up. Being more certain about what's going on would require actual instrumentation of the code and running things in your testing environment.